# I can't get the result I need from PHP's round()

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding

I cannot get the `round()` function to work correctly. Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
if ($con2 == "sf") {
    $formula = $num * 0.00694444;
    $formula = round($formula);
    $result = $num . $si . "<br>RESULT: " . $formula . $sf;
};
```

With this code, when `$num` is 144, the result is 0.99999936. However, I need that to be rounded to 1. Why is this happening and how can I get `round()` to behave the way I expect it to instead of this counter-intuitive way?

Comment: [It works for me](http://viper-7.com/46EJON).

Comment: When I try this out with $num = 144 I get '1' for $result. So could you please tell us what your other variables are ($si, $sf)?

Comment: $si $ sf are string variable for square inch and square feet. However $number is a user input number from a $num = $_POST['number']; so when I type 144 into the form it does not round, it just multiplies it by the 0.00694444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - so could you try this script and see what happens, this is working the with behaviour you're looking for when I enter 144:

```
<?
if($_POST){
    $num=$_POST["number"];
    $formula = $num * 0.00694444;
    $formula = round($formula);
    echo $formula;
} else {
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="number" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

try:

`$formula = round($formula, 0);`

Comment: the default for the second parameter should be zero anyway.

Comment: @Spudley You are completely right. I tested it without the 2nd argument and I still get `1` as an answer.

Comment: @Spudley I am guessing, but it may force `$num` to the proper type.  `$num` might originate as a string.

Comment: @SableFoste Nope. I tried `$formula = "144" * 0.00694444;` and the result is still `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the number of decimal places you want:

```
$formula = $num * 0.00694444;
$formula = round($formula,0);
echo $formula;
```

Comment: nope it still gives me the same answer without rounding 0.99999936

Comment: This is working for me - http://codepad.org/Ol2SPYdZ - could it be something to do with your other variables?

Comment: $number is a user input number from a $num = $_POST['number']; so when I type 144 into the form it does not round, it just multiplies it by the 0.00694444

Comment: Could you just try round(0.999999) and see what happens?

Comment: it gives me 1, but I am thinking the round function is getting confused on the user input maybe.